# Is there anything like TextMate for the web?

Tags: text-editor, textmate

Has anyone built a text editor that has somewhat the same functionality as TextMate but for the web?

It would be really cool to see something that:

- Doesn't have any GUI buttons
- Has all the base textmate keyboard shortcuts (e.g. highlight text and hit quotes key, and it wraps text in quotes, or hold ALT+SHIFT and highlight text and it highlights in a square).
- Allows you to use textmate language bundles :)

Does anything like that exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.
Emy Editor
See it on [www.amyeditor.com](http://www.amyeditor.com)

Answer (score 0):

it's called vim !
A screenshot of mine running in a terminal: http://viennot.biz/vim.png

EDIT: Maybe I misunderstood the question, try https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/

Comment: vim is also available as a *web* application!?

Comment: no, it's multiplatform, and you can use it to _build_ web applications. Maybe I misunderstood the question.
In that case I would recommand: https://mozillalabs.com/bespin

Comment: What is the name of the color scheme used in your vim screenshot?

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2340
But with some custom customizations